# How can I query posts from multiple roles?

Tags: wp-query

I'm using the code below from another answer to query posts from 1 custom role, eg "friends". I thought I could just comma separate the roles to list posts from more than one role, but this didn't work. Is there another way I can write it? I've tried `'role' => 'friends', 'enemies'` and `'role' => 'friends, enemies'` but I guess `get_users` only supports one role.

```
<?php
$friends = get_users( array( 'role' => 'friends' ) );
$friend_ids = array();

foreach( $friends as $friend ) 
$friend_ids[] = $friend->ID;

$news = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => implode( ',', $friend_ids ), 'post_type' => 'news', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the get_users() twice and merge the results:

```
<?php
$friends = get_users( array( 'role' => 'friends' ) );
$enemies = get_users( array( 'role' => 'enemies' ) );

$friends_n_foe = array_merge($friends, $enemies);

$IDs = array();

foreach( $friends_n_foe as $person ) {
    $IDs[] = $person->ID;
}

$news = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => implode( ',', $IDs ), 'post_type' => 'news', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Brady, that ones definitely going in the tool belt

Answer (score 1):

Below is function to get user ids for roles, from http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/get-wordpress-users-by-role/

```
function getUsersByRole( $roles ) {  
    global $wpdb;  
    if ( ! is_array( $roles ) ) {  
        $roles = explode( ",", $roles );  
        array_walk( $roles, 'trim' );  
    }  
    $sql = ' 
        SELECT  ID, display_name 
        FROM        ' . $wpdb->users . ' INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->usermeta . ' 
        ON      ' . $wpdb->users . '.ID              =       ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.user_id 
        WHERE   ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_key     =       \'' . $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities\' 
        AND     ( 
    ';  
    $i = 1;  
    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {  
        $sql .= ' ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_value LIKE    \'%"' . $role . '"%\' ';  
        if ( $i < count( $roles ) ) $sql .= ' OR ';  
        $i++;  
    }  
    $sql .= ' ) ';  
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY display_name ';  
    $userIDs = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );  
    return $userIDs;  
}
```

I should work... may be you have syntax error...

See in below page..
Show Posts From Several Authors
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters